# jQuery $.post success function never fires

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I have a $.post which using Fiddler I can see always posts successfully but my success function is never fired.

A successful post to the url returns a  1 or failure returns a 0, on each occasion I have tested it returns the expected value of 1 so I'm at a lost as to what I'm doing wrong?

```
if ($('#mycheckbox').prop('checked')) {
    $.post('/base/MailingList/Subscribe/',
        {
            listId: $('#mycheckbox').val(),
            name: $('#subscriber-name').val(),
            email: $("#subscriber-email").val()
        },
        function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        });
}
```

Comment: What does the browser console tells you?

Comment: If the response in fiddler shows a 200 status then it should work. Unless you're in IE7, in which the console.log call will break the success function.

Comment: The console shows me the expected response of "200 OK" which is the source of my confusion and reason for my post.

I am using Chrome and FireFox for testing at the moment.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Stick another function as a final callback. That function will run in the failure case.

The way jquery recommends doing it is this:

```
var jqxhr = $.post( "example.php", function() {
   alert( "success" );
})
.done(function() {
    alert( "second success" );
})
.fail(function() {
    alert( "error" );
})
.always(function() {
    alert( "finished" );
 });
```

Comment: Interestingly this example works for me. I will integrate this back into my app and if all is working still as expected I will mark as the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will help or not, but I always use fully qualified urls when I do any asynchronous calls.  You may want to try:

```
$.post('http://mydomain.com/base/MailingList/Suscribe/', ...
```

Additionally, you will likely want your handling function to recieve all three argument from the callback (data, textStatus, jqXHR).  This way, you can look at the txtStatus to verify if you have success or not.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was header with wrong MIME type ("application/json" instead of "text") in php file on server. If you send header that doesn't match type of data cause an error and $.post calls fail function.